Help finding a conservation law for a functional
I am trying to find a conservation law for the following functional: $$J(y)=\int_0^1 xyy'^2 dx$$
I am trying to use Noether's Theorem to accomplish this, and I know that the infinitesimal generators of the variational symmetry that will enable me to use the theorem (if they exist) will be given by the following formula: $$\xi\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+(\eta'-y'\xi')\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+\xi'f=0$$ where $f(x, y, y') = xyy'^2.$ I got a result for the generators using this equation, but I'm not sure that they make sense. I was wondering if someone else could tell me their results from this approach to check my results. Thank you!

Please show your results.

The generators I derived were $\xi = c_1x^2+c_2$ and $\eta = c_1\sqrt{y}+c_2$.

They don't satisfy your second equation.

I understand; I am interested if someone else could derive their own result that might elucidate any error I made in my derivation.
